# How to get fiscal year in a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a stored procedure and from the c# code the 'serverdate' is passed to the SP.serverdate is the value of System.Datetime.now().

How can i find the fiscal year from that serverdate in sp?

The fiscal year is taken as "April 1 to March 31".

Comment: How are you wanting to represent the fiscal year? i.e. in what format?  E.g. a string like `'2012-2013'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) >= 4 THEN 
        CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE())+1 AS VARCHAR(4))
    ELSE 
        CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE())-1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
    END AS fiscal
```

Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: if the getdate() gives value as 2013-apr-12 00:00:00.000,then the above query give wrong answer.ie,the actual answer is 2013-2014,but the above query gives the answer as '2012-2013'. declare @date datetime
set @date='2013-apr-12 00:00:00.000'
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(month, @date) >= 4 THEN 
        CAST(DATEPART(year, @date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(year, @date)+1 AS VARCHAR(4))
    ELSE 
        CAST(DATEPART(year, @date)-1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(year, @date) AS VARCHAR(4))
    END AS fiscal

Answer (score 0):

These are Oracle queries but they will work in SQL SERVER if you select from your table or SQL SERVER system table such as "dual" in Oracle:

```
SELECT start_date, Add_Months(start_date-1, 12) end_date
  FROM
 (
  SELECT Add_Months(Trunc(SYSDATE, 'YY'), 3) start_date
    FROM dual
 )
 /

Output:

Start_Date  End_Date
-------------------------
4/1/2013    3/31/2014
```

Fiscal Year - Annual table "on the fly":

```
SELECT (start_date-1)+ LEVEL  Fiscal_Year
  FROM
(
  SELECT start_date, Add_Months(start_date-1, 12) end_date
    FROM
  (
   SELECT Add_Months(Trunc(SYSDATE, 'YY'), 3) start_date
     FROM dual
  )
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (end_date+1)-start_date
/

Output:

FISCAL_YEAR
------------
4/1/2013
4/2/2013
4/3/2013
....
....
3/31/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working around SYSDATE then:

```
select CASE
         when substr(to_char(SYSDATE, 'ddmmyyyy'), 3, 2) IN
              ('01', '02', '03') THEN
          substr(to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, -12), 'ddmmyyyy'), 5, 4)
         else
          substr(to_char(SYSDATE, 'ddmmyyyy'), 5, 4)
       END
  from dual;
```

If you want to go for any random date,change to ddmmyyyy format.Below is for a sample date:

```
 select case 
when substr('17012014' ,3,2) in ('01','02','03') then SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('17012014','ddmmyyyy'),-12),'ddmmyyyy'),5,4)

else
substr(to_char(to_date('17012014','ddmmyyyy'),'ddmmyyyy'),5,4)
end
 from DUAL;
```